# Create trigger before insert in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I created a trigger before inserting into the employee table to calculate its age, but trying to insert into the employee table returns the following erro **Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'employee' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
  ssn INT(20) NOT NULL,  
  name_person VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  birth_date DATE NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY (ssn))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
  ssn_employee INT(20) NOT NULL,
  job_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  age INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ssn_employee),  
  FOREIGN KEY (ssn_employee)
  REFERENCES person (ssn)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;    

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER employeeAge
BEFORE INSERT ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
    DECLARE dob DATE;
    DECLARE ssn_employee1 int;
    SELECT new.ssn_employee INTO ssn_employee1;
    SELECT person.birth_date into dob FROM person WHERE ssn = ssn_employee1;
    UPDATE employee
    SET new.age = DATEDIFF(dob, GETDATE());     
END
DELIMITER;$$
```

Comment: Seems to be pretty clear.  You cannot do Update in the middle of Insert into the same table.

Comment: You can use generated column for age.

Comment: See https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_insert.php

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I'm a beginner and the tips clarified. I did this:

````
```lang_sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER employeeAge
BEFORE INSERT ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
    DECLARE dob DATE;
    DECLARE ssn_employee1 int;
    SELECT new.ssn_employee INTO ssn_employee1;
    SELECT person.birth_date into dob FROM person WHERE ssn = ssn_employee1;   
    SET new.age = TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, NOW());    
END;
DELIMITER $$
````